# Jump to line texmaker not working (filename follows best practice and synctex.gz is generated)

Tags: texmaker

I just started using Latex and encountered the problem that the jump to line feature in texmaker does not work. I already ruled out the usual culprits (filename and generation of synctex file) and do not know how to proceed further. I am using the current version of Miktex and Texmaker on a Windows 10 machine.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that the file path containing the tex file had an "ä" in it. So I guess not only the file itself but also the file path must not contain any umlauts.